# Ruby 2.0.0 with gem kamelopard -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I´m new to Ruby and the gem kamelopard.

I have installed RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [i386-mingw32], and kamelopard 0.0.15

When trying to run this program

```
                            require 'rubygems'
                            require 'kamelopard'

                            include Kamelopard
                            include Kamelopard::Functions

                            make_function_path(10,
                                            :latitude => Line.interpolate(38.8, 40.3),
                                            :longitude => Cubic.interpolate(-112.4, -111.9, -0.5, -113, 0.5, -110),
                                            :altitude => Line.interpolate(10000, 2000),
                                            :heading => Line.interpolate(0, 90),
                                            :tilt => Line.interpolate(40.0, 90),
                                            :altitudeMode => :absolute,
                                            #:extrude => 1,
                                            #:roll => 0,
                                            :show_placemarks => 1,
                                            :duration => Quadratic.interpolate(2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                            ) do |a, v|
                                            if v.has_key? :callback_value then
                                                            v[:callback_value] += 1
                                            else
                                                            v[:pause] = 0.01
                                                            v[:callback_value] = 1
                                            end
                                            v
                            end

                            name_document 'Functions test'
                            name_folder 'Placemarks'
                            name_tour 'Function test'

                            write_kml_to 'doc.kml'
```

I get the following error message, I would appreciate your help to understand why.

```
            C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard/classes.rb:53:in `<module:Kamelopard>'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard/classes.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
                                            from C:/Users/Dasaecor/Documents/Kamelopard/Prueba.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Many thanks in advance for your help. David

After installing the "bundler" and "libxml-ruby (2.7.0 x86-mingw32)" gems, i still get the following error message:

```
                            C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- libxml_ruby (LoadError)
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0-x86-mingw32/lib/libxml.rb:8:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0-x86-mingw32/lib/libxml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0-x86-mingw32/lib/xml.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard/classes.rb:55:in `<module:Kamelopard>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard/classes.rb:52:in `<top (required)>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kamelopard-0.0.15/lib/kamelopard.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
                                                            from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
                                                            from C:/Users/Dasaecor/Documents/Kamelopard/Prueba.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: ok, problem solved. The gem list required is in the developer's website: https://code.google.com/p/liquid-galaxy/source/browse/#git%2Fkamelopard in the gemlist. These are: "bundler", "rspec", "libxml-ruby", "json", "hierclust", and "rubyzip". Tks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the kamelopard (0.15) files, classes.rb, begins with this code:

```
module Kamelopard
    require 'bundler/setup'
    require 'singleton'
    require 'xml'
    require 'yaml'
    require 'erb'
    require 'cgi'
```

The cgi, erb, yaml, and singleton modules are part of the Ruby Standard Library, so your ruby installation provides those modules.  However, the 'xml' and 'bundler/setup'  modules are not part of the ruby standard library.  You can install the Bundler gem to get rid of your error--but then you will get a similar error for 'xml'. There has been no 'xml' module in the Ruby Standard Library) since at least version 1.8.7, and there is no 3rd party gem named xml:

```
$ gem search xml

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

actionpack-xml_parser (1.0.1)
active_xml (0.0.3)
age_de_xml (0.1.0)
allhomes_xml (0.1.2)
android-xml (1.2.2)
anychart_xml_builder (0.0.12)
array-xml_serialization (0.1.0)
asir_xml (1.1.12)
axml (0.0.7)
baixarxml (0.0.4)
beardley-xml (1.1.1)
beerxml (0.3.0)
bio-blastxmlparser (1.1.1)
bio-lazyblastxml (0.4.0)
bio-nexml (1.1.0)
bio-phyloxml (0.9.0)
bio-raxml (0.1.0)
capcode-render-xml (0.1.0)
cocoa-xml (0.4.5)
codemodels-xml (0.1.2 java)
correios-sro-xml (0.2.1)
coupa-libxml-ruby (1.1.4)
cxml (0.1.0)
debugger-xml (0.3.3)
dfxml (0.2.2)
diff2xml (0.0.2)
dir-to-xml (0.3.3)
dm-xml-adapter (0.587)
dtefacil_xml_builder (0.0.11)
eim_xml (0.0.4)
eimxml (0.0.3.1)
elibri_xml_versions (0.1.11)
em-xmlrpc-client (1.0.1)
endeca_xml (0.9.0)
equivalent-xml (0.4.3)
evma_xmlpushparser (0.0.1)
excelxml (0.1.2)
fabulator-xml (0.0.5)
faster_xml_simple (0.5.0)
faster_xml_simple_reader (0.0.1)
fastxml (0.1.92)
flexmls_api (0.7.5)
flexmls_gems (0.2.9)
FlightXML2RESTDriver (0.1.4)
gccxml_gem (0.9.3 ruby x86-darwin-10 x86-darwin-11 x86-linux x86_64-linux, 0.9.2 universal-darwin-10 x86-cygwin x86-darwin-9 x86-mingw32)
gravitext-xmlprod (1.7.0 java)
hash2xml (0.0.1)
hash_to_xml (1.0.1)
hashtoxml (0.0.5)
iab-ActiveRecordBDBXml (0.2.0)
irxml (0.0.0)
jasmine_junitxml_formatter (0.1.0)
java2ruby-xmldsig (0.2)
javabean_xml (0.1.2)
jexml (0.1.0 jruby)
jrexml (0.5.3)
jrubyfx-fxmlloader (0.3 java, 0.0.1)
jxmlvalidator (0.1.2)
libxml-ext (0.4.2)
libxml-feed (0.0.1)
libxml-fixed-jruby (1.0.0 jruby)
libxml-jruby (1.0.0)
libxml-jruby-fixed (1.0.0 jruby)
libxml-ruby (2.7.0 ruby x86-mingw32, 1.1.4 x86-mswin32-60)
libxml-ruby-r19mingw (1.1.4)
libxml-to-hash (0.2.1)
libxml-xmlrpc (0.1.5)
libxml4r (0.2.6)
lustr-mxml (0.1.0)
magic-xml (0.2013.04.14)
magic_xml (0.1.1)
MergeAsXML (0.0.4)
mezza-testunitxml (0.1.6.1)
middleman-xmlvalidator (0.2.1)
MINT-scxml (1.1.7)
model_xml (1.0.13)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
mysql-xml (0.1.1)
nessus-xmlrpc (0.5.0)
nokogiri-xmlsec (0.0.4)
nom-xml (0.5.1)
objectify-xml (0.2.3)
oddb2xml (1.8.5)
olap4r-xmla (0.1.0)
open_xml (0.0.2)
open_xml_package (0.0.3)
opinionated-xml (0.1.0)
oracle_enhanced_plus_xmltype (0.0.5)
osheet-xmlss (1.0.0)
oxmlk (0.4.0)
oxmlrpc (0.2)
pacer-xml (0.2.4 java)
pg-xml (0.0.2)
pretty-xml (0.1.3)
prova-vhm-raw2xml (1.0.0)
pseudoxml (0.1.0)
qbxml (0.1.5)
qbxml-dtd6 (1.0.3)
rack-xml_stylesheet (0.0.1)
rails-xmlrpc (0.3.7)
rbgccxml (1.0.4)
rdbxml (2.4.13.2)
rdf-rdfxml (1.1.0.1)
rdf-xml (0.0.3)
rexml-expansion-fix (1.0.1)
rivsc-xmlattributes (1.0.0)
ROXML (3.0.0)
roxml (3.3.1)
rraxml (0.1.2)
rspec-xml (0.0.6)
rsxml (0.4.1)
rtiss_libxml_to_hash (0.3.0)
ruby-xml-mapper (1.0.8)
ruby-xml-smart (0.2.99.3, 0.1.12.1 i486-linux)
rubyjedi-testunitxml (0.1.5.20100616141003)
rubysl-rexml (2.0.2)
rubysl-xmlrpc (2.0.0)
sads_xml (0.0.4)
salad-xml_page (0.3.4)
sandozxmlconv (1.0.0)
scxml (0.1.0)
signed_xml (1.0.1)
simple-xml (1.0.0)
sixarm_ruby_rexml (2.1.0)
sixarm_ruby_rexml_element_new_with_options (1.2.0)
sixarm_ruby_xml_load (2.1.0)
sixarm_ruby_xml_strip (2.1.0)
smile-xml (1.0.3 java jruby)
sprout-mxml-bundle (0.1.13)
test_xml (0.1.6)
testunitxml (0.1.5)
texml (0.5.0)
the-experimenters-rdf-rdfxml (0.3.4)
thinp_xml (0.0.15)
tiny_xml_builder (0.0.4)
tkxml (0.3.1)
to_xml (0.1.1)
ts-xml (1.0.3)
tuxml (0.0.1)
validates_xml (1.0.3)
vcr-xml (0.0.3)
vtd-xml (0.0.3 java)
vtd_xml (0.0.6 java)
vxml-tools (1.0.0)
wbxml (0.0.2)
wbxml-npn47 (0.0.2)
whm_xml (0.3.2)
wordpress-xmlrpc (0.0.11)
wordpress-xmlrpc-api (0.0.1)
wpxml_parser (0.0.1)
xml-focus (0.0.1)
xml-fu (0.2.0)
xml-magic (0.1.1)
xml-mapping (0.9.1)
xml-motor (0.1.6)
xml-object (0.9.93)
xml-purifier (0.1.4)
xml-registry (0.2.3)
xml-sax-machines (0.4.2)
xml-simple (1.1.3)
xml-sitemap (1.3.3)
xml-smart (0.3.9)
xml-spec (0.3.0)
xml-to-haml (0.1.7)
xml2csv (0.0.1)
xml2go (0.0.3)
xml_active (0.0.6)
xml_contacts_extractor (0.0.5)
xml_convert (0.1.0)
xml_data_builder (1.0.0)
xml_errors_parser (0.0.2)
xml_escape (0.0.2)
xml_file_renamer (0.0.8)
xml_fixtures (0.1.1)
xml_hate (0.8.3.4)
xml_mapper (0.5.8)
xml_mini (0.1.0)
xml_node_stream (1.0.2)
xml_resource (2.0.5)
xml_schema (0.2.0)
xml_schema_mapper (0.0.12)
xml_security (0.0.3)
xml_serialization (0.1.2)
xml_signature (0.1)
xml_soccer (0.0.4)
xml_spec (0.1.0)
xml_split (0.0.2)
xml_stream_parser (0.3.0)
xml_to_json (0.0.2)
xml_uglifier (0.0.2)
xmlblog-acts_as_versioned (0.6.5)
XMLCanonicalizer (1.0.1)
xmlcanonicalizer (0.1.2)
xmlcellent (0.1.0)
xmlcodec (0.3.2)
xmlconv (1.0.1)
xmlconv2 (2.0.0)
xmldsig (0.2.4)
xmldsig-fiscalizer (0.2.5)
xmldsign (0.2.0)
XmlEasy (0.0.2)
xmlelements (0.1.2)
xmlenc (0.1.3)
xmlhash (1.3.6)
xmlhasher (0.0.6)
xmlish (0.0.1)
xmlize (0.1.1)
xmlobject (0.2)
xmlparsable (1.5.4)
xmlparser (0.7.2.1)
xmlpipe2_indexer (0.0.2)
xmlpretty (0.1.0)
xmlresume2x (0.2.1)
XMLROCS (0.0.1)
xmlrpc-endpoint (0.2.1)
xmlrpc-rack (0.0.1)
xmlrpc-rack_server (0.0.1)
xmlrpc-streaming (0.1.0)
xmlrpc_controller (0.0.7)
xmlrpcs (0.1.3)
xmlscan (0.3.0)
xmlsec (0.0.6)
xmlsec-ruby (0.0.7)
xmlsec-shim (1.2.18.2)
xmlsig (0.0.3)
xmlsoccer (0.1.0)
xmlss (1.0.0)
xmlstats (1.6.1)
xmlstreamin (0.0.1)
xmlstruct (1.0.0)
xmltv (0.8.7)
xmltv2html (0.8.0)
xmlvalidate (0.1.0)
yard-xml (0.1.3)
yaxml (0.1)
yob-roxml (3.1.6)
```

It looks like the gem was recently updated, so I would try to get in contact with the author and ask him/her where/what the xml module is.

Okay, if you install the libxml-ruby gem, that provides an xml module, which can be required by kamelopard.

Comment: @Dasaecor, I figured out how to get the xml module...check the end of the post.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. I have installed the "bundler" and libxml-ruby (2.7.0 x86-mingw32) gems. I still get an error message. I am going to add the information to may original post.

Comment: @Dasaecor, I have tested your code in ruby 2.0.0-p487, and it produces no errors when the bundler gem and the libxml-ruby gem are installed. Okay, you are on Windows...go here: http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/, and read the Windows specific install instructions for libxml-ruby.  Well, those instructions are terrible(for instance there is no `win32` gem), so I think you are going to have to google around to figure out how to install libxml-ruby and its dependencies on windows.  You might want to start here: http://vairoj.com/2010/06/installing-libxml-ruby-on-windows-the-painless-way.html